# Analysing and formatting JSON using PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table called api_details where i dump the below JSON value into the JSON column raw_data.
Now i need to make a report from this JSON string and the **expected output** is something like below,

```
action_name.              sent_timestamp                           Sent. Delivered
campaign_2475             1600416865.928737 - 1601788183.440805.    7504. 7483
campaign_d_1084_SUN15_ex  1604220248.153903 - 1604222469.087918.   63095. 62961
```

**Below is the sample JSON OUTPUT**

```
{
  "header": [
    "#0 action_name",
    "#1 sent_timestamp",
    "#0 Sent",
    "#1 Delivered"
    
  ],
  "name": "campaign - lifetime",
  "rows": [
    [
      "campaign_2475",
      "1600416865.928737 - 1601788183.440805",
      7504,
      7483
    ],
    [
      "campaign_d_1084_SUN15_ex",
      "1604220248.153903 - 1604222469.087918",
      63095,
      62961
    ],
    [
      "campaign_SUN15",
      "1604222469.148829 - 1604411016.029794",
      63303,
      63211 
    ]
  ],
  "success": true
}
```

I tried like below, but is not getting the results.I can do it using python by lopping through all the elements in row list.

**But is there an easy solution in PostgreSQL(version 11).**

```
SELECT raw_data->'rows'->0 
  FROM api_details
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` function such as

```
SELECT (j.value)->>0 AS action_name,
       (j.value)->>1 AS sent_timestamp,
       (j.value)->>2 AS Sent,
       (j.value)->>3 AS Delivered
  FROM api_details
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(raw_data->'rows') AS j
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f394d3661d52c140488b61b6163a11d7)</kbd>

P.S. in this case the data type of `raw_data` is assumed to be `JSONB`, otherwise the argument within the function `raw_data->'rows'` should be replaced with `raw_data::JSONB->'rows'` in order to perform explicit type casting.

Comment: Got this error   ERROR:  function jsonb_array_elements(json) does not exist
LINE 7:  CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(raw_data->'rows') AS j
                    ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 229

Comment: Hi @Linu , seems that you need to replace `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(raw_data->'rows')` with `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(raw_data::JSONB->'rows')` , e.g. `raw_data` is not of type `JSON(B)` in your case(probably a of a `TEXT` type), while in our demo in the answer it's of type `JSONB`. Consider this new [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bb652c7094e8281e9d806e5d3cb9c381) for your case.

Comment: The casts of `j.value` to `jsonb` should not be necessary